# Cordova camera plugin, obtain full image path from gallery [ANDROID]

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, camera, gallery

I am trying to get an image from the gallery with cordova camera plugin, this is the way I am doing it:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
  quality: 50,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  mediaType: Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
});
```

But in my 'onSuccess' function I get the image URI in the format:

```
"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1509"
```

And I want the URI with the full path to the image, just like I get it if I use the camera instead:

```
"file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20150710_124222.jpg"
```

Reading the official documentation I have seen that the only thing I am supposed to do is to set the property 'DestinationType' to 'FILE_URI', which is already set as you can see above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found a plugin that converts the URI in 'content://...' format into full file path, it isn't the perfect solution but it is the one has worked for me, the plugin is [cordova-plugin-filepath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-filepath), I use it in the onSuccess callback for the getCamera function:

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) {
  window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(imageURI, function(result) {
    // onSuccess code
    imageURI = 'file://' + result;
    . . .
  }, function (error) {
    // onError code here
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know how to make the user choose between the camera and gallery!

Comment: Well then just create 2 buttons, one will set the property 'sourceType' to 'Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM', and the other one will set the same property to 'Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA'

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using single button with the help of **confirm box**:

```
var txt=confirm("Select photo source");
if(txt==true){
         navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,saveToPhotoAlbum: true,sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA});
}
else{
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,saveToPhotoAlbum: true,sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY});
}
```

If ok,then camera opens
else if you click cancel, then galery opens

**you can also customize ok-cancel button of confirm botton according to your need.**

Answer (score 0):

I guess The problem in your code is here

```
mediaType: Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA,
```

either remove this line or make it

```
 mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
```

happy coding....